# Business Entity contains persistence functionality

Tags: design-patterns, persistence, business-objects, object-persistence

Is there a name for the pattern in which business objects contain their own persistence mechanism?  For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        // save to database
    }
}
```

I'm not an advocate of this design - I'm just curious if there is a name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)